# Regular expression not working in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have markups enclosing text in a word document.
If the markups enclose valid text or any **valid** dynamic field, the regular expression works :

[image]

But the second line, which contains an invalid cross-reference is not found by the search engine... whereas I need to find and delete it actually.

**Edit on the 25/01/2018 :**

Thanks for your answer.

1. I run the search from a macro, that is right. I have no error from the macro, the sequence [SP]*invalid reference*[\SP] is just not found
2. I actually want to select *anything* between the two markups (table, image, text, reference, fields ...) *including* the markups

Comment: Please use the [edit] link and add to your problem description the Word field code that's generating the error. You might also trying searching with the special character for picking up fields: ^d

Comment: You have added the VBA tag. Are you using this search in VBA or not?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The person is not using RegEx, but Word's built-in search functionality. I'm going to edit RegEx out of the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Based on the screen shots: Everything between [SP] and [/SP], inclusive. But I'm guessing the field code (bad cross-ref) is getting in the way with the Wildcards.

Comment: Beside searching the field code (^d) you might also try turning on the display of field codes before running the Find (Alt+F9).

Comment: It is not possible to find fields using a wildcard search in Word. You can either unlink all fields beforehand (using Ctrl+A followed by Ctrl+Shift+F9) or do the job using a VBA macro.

Comment: @Cindy I will try to turn on the display of fields and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to find fields via wildcard search. I also cannot find an error field by searching for ^d without wildcard.

Therefore: use two loops in your code. Before searching for [SP], iterate over all fields, identify those with error and delete / Replace with a space:

```
Dim fld As Field, ran As Range

For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If InStr(1, fld.Result.text, "Erreur !") >= 0 Then
        Set ran = fld.Result
        fld.Delete
        ran.InsertAfter " "
    End If
Next fld
```

After that, run your normal wildcard search/replace for [SP]...[/SP] and you should be fine.

Comment: After various trials, I came to the same conclusion as you. Thanks